# What symbols are unique to the various denominations?

Tags: denomination-survey, symbolism

In reading the meta discussion about [what logo should be used for Christianity.SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436), I got to wondering what symbols are unique to various denominations. Note: I'm not looking for symbols which are *common* across Christianity -- such as the Cross -- but which are more narrowly focused.

For example, the following symbols are -- as far as I know -- uniquely Catholic:

[image: Chi Rho]
[image: Holy Name Monogram]
[image: "M" for Mary]

An example of a symbol which *I think* is denominationally unique (and I *think* is Episcopal) is this:

[Shield http://aldiechurch.com/images/episshield.png](http://aldiechurch.com/images/episshield.png)

What other denominationally unique symbols are there?

Comment: This is an interesting question but could result in an endless list of logos and emblems of different denominations and national/international church groups. We'd need to consider how to avoid that.

Comment: I meant to make this a community wiki question as there isn't, by definition, a single answer yet there can be lots of very good ones... but I don't seem to have the ability to do that.  Do I need a higher rep score?  Can an admin make the change?

Comment: @Audio only mods can do that since the great "Should be CW" edict of 2010. But it's up to them to make an exception to the "no list" rule.

Comment: I've seen the first one ([Chi Rho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_Rho)) in several Lutheran churches here in Norway, so I don't think that one's exclusively Catholic. Also, see [Christian symbolism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_symbolism).

Comment: Okay, it makes sense that the Chi Rho isn't only Catholic: it's a symbol that goes back to antiquity as those are the first two letters of "Christ" in Greek. I am accustomed to seeing that as a symbol referring to a Catholic priest.  The IHS monogram was invented with advent of the Society of the Holy Name whose aim was to combat blasphemy... I thought that was post-reformation but maybe it wasn't... or maybe it was a crossover symbol?

Comment: When I was a boy I attended a "Covenant Church", which I think is a pretty tiny denomination, but we had the Chi-Rho symbol in our church. I remember wondering what "PX" meant as a kid.

Answer (score 2):

The Chi-Ro symbol dates back to 312 AD when Constantine had a vision, and was told to fight under that symbol at the Battle of Milvan Bridge. It is truly "catholic" in the sense that it is universal to all of Christianity. [You may have heard of a city in Egypt that the Copts named after this symbol ;) ]

IHS is also fairly common- I've seen that in Baptist churches and Anglican ones. I believe that is supposed to be the Greek form of Jesus but I don't know. (maybe someone should ask!)

The last one is just a coat of arms for The Episcopal Church, much like the emblem of the Holy See.

Comment: IHS is Latin, isn't it? Jesus Saviour of Men (where L. *homo* is gender-neutral, but is traditionally translated into E. as *man*, which used to be gender-neutral but no longer is).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect most Protestant denominations in America and Europe have some sort of official logo. For example:

Southern Baptists

[image]

Christian & Missionary Alliance

[image]

Evangelical Lutheran Church of America
[image]

United Methodists
[image]

Etc etc. I'm sure we could list hundreds.

Answer (score 2):

I would not be surprised if every church had some form of logo. Here are the ones I know:

Lutheran cross:[image]

ELCA [image]

Papal flag:[image: Papal flag]

Episcopal[image]

(American) Anglican[image]

Baptist[image]

Methodist[image]

Orthodox (and Eastern Catholic)
[image]

Russian Orthodox (foot goes opposite way)
[image: Russian]

Comment: What's the difference b/w the Orthodox and the Russian Orthodox? They look pretty much the same to me?

Answer (score 2):

For good measure, the Church of England (Anglican Church - i.e. what Episcopalians diverged from):

[image]